# Generic rules to build numeric multipliers from truth tables

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation

I have some truth tables, mostly AND, based on 0, 1, -1 which I am using for Math operations:

Example 1:

```
var a,b,c;
if(a ==  1 && b == 1) c = 0;
if(a ==  1 && b == 0) c = 0;
if(a == -1 && b == 1) c = 0;
if(a == -1 && b == 0) c = 1;
```

Example 2:

```
var a,b,c;
if(a ===  1 && b === 1) c =  1;
if(a ===  1 && b === 0) c =  1;
if(a === -1 && b === 1) c =  1;
if(a === -1 && b === 0) c = -1;
```

For instance, the first one could be expressed as follows:

```
c = (a>>1)*(b-1);
```

I would like to convert also the second truth table using only Math or Bitwise Operators, how can it be done?

Is there any generic rule to easily create such kind of one-line expression?

Comment: btw, you have not boolean values insode. can you have other values than showed?

Comment: @NinaScholz: correct, I do not want booleans, the result shall be numeric so that I can use it directly inside the next math operation.

Comment: "truth table" and "bit manipulation" generally refer to binary logic. Looks like you have trinary logic?

Comment: @Bergi: maybe. I am using usually 0 and -1 as falsy, but not always. Usually there are only two of these three switches involved at a time: either 0/1 or -1/1 I am still interested in some generic implementation rules involving all three values, if this is what You meant, and You have some hints, that would be great.

Comment: TBH I think that your `if` cascade is the most cleanest and readable, especially since it is not a total function (9 cases! - `a == 0`  and `b == -1` are missing).

Comment: Alternatively, you should first normalise your values to booleans, and then just use normal boolean operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a generic superoptimizer such as this one I wrote (unfortunately not very user friendly): https://github.com/falk-hueffner/sematrope

This will give you `(a + b) >>> 31` for your first example and `((a + b) | b) & a` for the second.

For a more systematic approach, you can convert -1/1 to 0/1 by `(x >> 1) + 1`, do regular logic operations with `|&^`, and then (if needed) convert 0/1 to -1/1 by `x ^ (x - 1)`.

Comment: That's awesome!

Answer (score 0):

If `a` is always `1` or `-1` and `b` is always `1` or `0`, and you're OK to use a boolean operator (`||`), then

```
c = b || a
```

should do it...

```js
const c = (a, b) => b || a

console.log(c( 1, 1)) // 1
console.log(c( 1, 0)) // 1
console.log(c(-1, 1)) // 1
console.log(c(-1, 0)) //-1
```

Comment: I am aware that I can use Number(boolean) to convert it at the end, but I am asking for a math expression.

Comment: @deblocker What about `Number(boolean)`? I couldn't really understand what you mean... My example will return a number, not a boolean